# Breakpoints and F statistics in strucchange package

Tags: r, breakpoints

As far as I know the breakpoint should correspond to the observation which maximizes the F statistics, but I can't see any meaningful association between the F statistics and the timing of the break. What do I get wrong?

```
y <- c(rnorm(30), 2+rnorm(20))  # 1 breakpoint
f <- Fstats(y ~ 1)               # calculate F statistics
f$breakpoint                     # breakpoint Fstats suggests
which(f$Fstats == max(f$Fstats)) # observation with max F statistics
order(f$Fstats)                  # observations ordered by F statistics
```

As can be seen the observation of the breakpoint is not the observation with the highest F statistics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `y` is not class `ts`. So the output became a bit curious `ts` data and unfortunately you failed to interpret it.

```
set.seed(1)
y <- c(rnorm(30), 2+rnorm(20))
ts.y <- ts(y, start = 1, frequency = 1)  # change `y` into class `ts`

ts.f <- Fstats(ts.y ~ 1)

ts.f$breakpoint  # [1] 30
ts.f$Fstats
 # Time Series:
 # Start = 7       # this means ts.f$Fstats[1] is 7th
which(ts.f$Fstats == max(ts.f$Fstats)) # [1] 24  # ts.f$Fstats[24] is 30th

plot(ts.f)
lines(breakpoints(ts.f))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, now I get it!